# Android: ValueAnimator Flashes Colors So Quickly?

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm using the property animator ValueAnimator to animate logo color change. The animation works, but the colors flash so quickly. How do I control them and make the colors change slowly and smoothly?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    private void animateLogo(){ 
    ImageView imgLogo = findViewById(R.id.imgview_logo);
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofArgb();
    animator.setDuration(5000);
    animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    animator.setIntValues(R.color.colorGoldNew,
            R.color.dbIndex0,
            R.color.dbIndex5,
            R.color.dbIndex6);
    animator.addUpdateListener(animation ->

            imgLogo.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue()))
    );
    animator.start(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ArgbEvaluator` [evaluates](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ArgbEvaluator#evaluate(float,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) based on 32-bit int value representing colors. You are currently using R class ID int values which I suspect is messing up the evaluator.

I have used the respective int color value by using [`getColor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getColor(int))

```
    private void animateLogo(){
    ImageView imgLogo = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    ValueAnimator colorAnim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(getColor(R.color.colorGoldNew),getColor(R.color.dbIndex0),getColor(R.color.dbIndex5),getColor(R.color.dbIndex6));
    colorAnim.setDuration(5000);
    colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    colorAnim.addUpdateListener(valueAnimator -> imgLogo.setColorFilter((int)colorAnim.getAnimatedValue()) );
    colorAnim.start();
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You're right, appreciate your help thank you. Now it's working perfectly.